# What type of encoding is this text?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I have a .NET project and somewhere in the code it has this text:

```
Áíäñéêü
```

What type of encoding is this and how can I get the original text?

Comment: Change the encoding in your code editor, until you find something that make sense in the context of your code.  Or check when the code was written, and on what operating system (and possibly the language of the OS). Probably you can have good guess, and so you can find the old encoding.

Comment: This _could_ be a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (Python example): `'Áíäñéêü'.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1253')` returns `'Ανδρικό'` which appears to me as a valid Greek word?